# Data from SQLite database saved in one activity, can't be shown in other activity

Tags: android, sqlite, android-spinner

In my app, I'm using an activity to add new courses and save them in the SQLite database. But when I try to access the added courses in an other activity to show them in an Spinner, the table seems to empty.

This is my code to save a course (first activity):

```
SQLiteHelperCourse courseDbHelper = new SQLiteHelperCourse(this);
    SQLiteDatabase dbw = courseDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    String courseNameString, yearString, semesterString, creditsString;
    AlertCourseError courseAlert = new AlertCourseError();

    if(v.getId() == R.id.btnSaveCourse)
    {
        if(!etCourseName.getText().toString().matches("") || !etCredits.getText().toString().matches(""))
        {
            courseNameString = etCourseName.getText().toString();
            yearString = yearSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
            semesterString = semesterSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
            creditsString = etCredits.getText().toString();

            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(CourseEntry.COLUMN_NAME_COURSE_NAME, courseNameString);
            values.put(CourseEntry.COLUMN_NAME_YEAR, yearString);
            values.put(CourseEntry.COLUMN_NAME_SEMESTER, semesterString);
            values.put(CourseEntry.COLUMN_NAME_CREDITS, creditsString);
            dbw.insert(CourseEntry.TABLE_NAME, CourseEntry.COLUMN_NAME_NULLABLE, values);
        }
}
```

This is the code to show the saved courses in a Spinner (second activity)

```
SQLiteDatabase dbr = courseDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    String[] projection = { CourseEntry.COLUMN_NAME_COURSE_NAME };
    final ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    Cursor curs = dbr.query(CourseEntry.TABLE_NAME, projection, null, null,
            null, null, null);
    curs.moveToFirst();

    while (curs.moveToNext()) {
        list.add(curs.getString(curs.getColumnIndexOrThrow(CourseEntry.COLUMN_NAME_COURSE_NAME)));
    }

    final StableArrayAdapter adapter = new StableArrayAdapter(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);

    courseSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: If you are not sure if data were inserted properly, check the newly inserted id, `long insertedId = dbw.insert(CourseEntry.TABLE_NAME, CourseEntry.COLUMN_NAME_NULLABLE, values);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SQLiteHelper class instances have to be the same name. In the code above one is:

```
SQLiteDatabase dbw = courseDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
```

and the other one is:

```
SQLiteDatabase dbr = courseDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
```

Changed them both to: `SQLiteDatabase dbw = courseDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();`

And now it works perfectly.